# cambiar nls_date_format oracle

Tags: oracle

Mi oracle tiene ahora :

```
NLS_DATE_FORMAT     DD/MM/RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   SPANISH
```

Entonces ejecuto :

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';
alter session set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN';
```

Y lo cambia sin problemas, pero cuando cierro mi sql developer vuelve a la configuración en español, como puedo modificarlo para siempre?

He probado :

```
alter system set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR' scope=spfile;
```

Pero sigue igual

Comment: Deberias de probara asi `alter system set nls_date_format='mm-bb-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' scope=spfile;`

Comment: acabo de editar la pregunta con tu sugerencia

Comment: Encontre este [link](http://www.todoexpertos.com/categorias/tecnologia-e-internet/bases-de-datos/oracle/respuestas/1127580/formato-de-fechas-en-oracle) por la web

Comment: Has tratado de reiniciar la Base de Datos después de: alter system set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR' scope=spfile; ? y con usuario sysdba?